# Sorting an array of objects by keyname in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

How do I sort this array:

```
[{"qwe":4}, {"rty":5}, {"asd":2}]
```

To get this:

```
[{"asd":2}, {"qwe":4}, {"rty":5}]
```

So that the array is sorted by the name of the key of the objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That question wanted to sort by a known key that exists in each object in the array. This question wants to sort by the key name itself, which is different from object to object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this using [Array.sort(compareFunction)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) ?

```
var myArray =[{"qwe":4}, {"rty":5}, {"asd":2}];
myArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return (Object.keys(a)[0] > Object.keys(b)[0]) - 0.5;
});
console.log(myArray);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h8DJF/)**

Comment: Why the "- 0.5" though?

Answer (score 0):

**PSL**'s answer have one problem that is if your array has uppercase and lowercase keys i.e. "john", "Naveed" then this solution is not going to work correctly. Following changes need to be done:

```
let source = [{"john": 12},{"Ali": 10},{"Naveed": 18}];

var target = source.sort(function(a,b){
 return (Object.keys(a)[0].toLowerCase() > Object.keys(b)[0].toLowerCase()) - 0.5;
});
console.log(target);
```